# MySQLHow to select records without duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql

**Table Name:** Order

**Columns:** ID & NAME & DATE

With the following records :

```
1 | starone | 2016
1 | starone | 2016
2 | mogaone | 2017
9 | starone | 2016
```

> And am looking to only select data without getting duplicates :

**Expected OUTPUT**

```
1 | starone | 2016
2 | mogaone | 2017
9 | starone | 2016
```

**So which query shall i use?**

Comment: `select distinct`...

Comment: How come you have duplicates in the first place, is `ID` not a primary key?

Comment: @jarlh `DISTINCT` OR `DISTINCTROW` , are `DISTINCT` will only show the duplicates record for only one time based on those 3 columns if matching in one entry ?

Comment: Here is some [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html)!

Comment: @HoneyBadger it's not a primary key. it's about order id

Comment: Forget about DISTINCTROW, it's just a silly MySQL synonym for ANSI SQL's DISTINCT.

Comment: In a well-formed table, this situation simply cannot occur. What is your PRIMARY KEY?

Answer (score 0):

Let's see what the documentation shows for us:

The **SELECT DISTINCT** statement is used to return only distinct (different) values.

Inside a table, a column often contains many duplicate values; and sometimes you only want to list the different (distinct) values.

```
SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2, ...
FROM table_name;
```

SOURCE: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

So, try it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, NAME, DATE
FROM Order;
```